# Best practice to customize UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image]

What is the best practice to create custom cell like this? since the data will be vary each cell. if the phone number not exist in the data, the price label and time will go up below the address and so on. how to calculate the size of the cell? now i am using this code to automatically calculate the size of the cell but this code only use 1 label the address label no other labels included.

code from the custom cell :

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
 [super awakeFromNib];
 self.titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
 self.addressLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

 CGFloat screenWidth = CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds);
 int gapWidth = 50;
 if (screenWidth == 414) {
 gapWidth = 20;
}

 // The cell width is half the screen width minus the gap between the cells
// The gap should be slightly larger than the minium space between cells set 
for the flow layout to prevent layout and scrolling issues
 CGFloat cellWidth = (screenWidth - gapWidth);
 [self.addressLabel addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.addressLabel
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual
                                                       toItem:nil
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                     constant:cellWidth]];

}
```

Comment: if you style of each cell will be different according to data then best way is to make types of cells , and make the nib of those custom cell, during creating cells check type of cell and load data according it.

Comment: Firstly use constraints instead of hard coded pixel values, secondly look into using anchors instead of NSLayoutConstraint like this. It will make you life simpler. Thirdly you should be able to define this entire cell in a xib file with constraints added in IB. Stack views can also help with simplifying this type of layout.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
This basically means your tableview will guess the height of your cell based on its content.

Here is the doc:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html

And a great tutorial:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

So to help you on your case, you will need to nil the text present in your labels, so that it's height will be 0 based on the data you receive from your api. Also as you have icons on the side, you will need to hide them as well.
Be sure to set all the constraints from the top to the bottom of your cell, so that the tableview will be able to understand and guess the height.
Also don't forget to gave an estimatedRowHeight in `viewdidload`:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
```